# facebook permission dialog pop-up like an overlay on the same page

Tags: facebook, oauth, dialog, x-facebook-platform

I have seen that APP Permission dialog for music /song apps show up on the same page.

and for the other apps it opens new tab OR does redirect.

Is it possible to have the same permission dialog for game app ?

for ex If user don't have Saavn app and they click on appname link It will show permission dialog as an Overlay as shown below : 
[image]

For my App the permission dialog takes user to new page as shown below:
[image]

My app settings for authenticated referrals : [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable [Authenticated Referrals](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals) per the instructions in Facebook's documentation - this is all controlled in your app settings and if you're using the Facebook PHP SDK won't require any code changes

Comment: I added new permissions but still it is not working. any weird settings I might be missing ?

Comment: It works the same old way. It takes user to new page to ask for permission. It does not popup on the same page as shown in the image.

Comment: I find out the difference between "Saavn App's link" and "My App's link".   Saavn's App has : display=async and myapp has : display=page

Comment: Are you sure you enabled authenticated referrals? if you do, clicks (from new users) of posts from your app on facebook trigger the dialog directly instead of going to your app and requiring you to redirect the users

Comment: And what's your problem? you haven't told us what isn't working - are you sure the link you're clicking was posted by the app, and links back to the app, and you're doing so from a user that hasn't authorised the app before

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12875/discussion-between-user583726-and-igy)